# Error: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, python-3.8, django-2.2

I'm developing websystem in Django, when I write a login function gives me this error:

`NoReverseMatch at /login/ Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

I checked the code a hundred times but there is something I'm missing and can't find the solution. I've been stuck on this for a while, can't seem to fix this error.
The other parts from the website are working fine.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')

def loginPage(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if request.GET.get('next'):
                return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
            else:
                return redirect('index')

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),

    path('', views.index, name="index"),  
]
```

**login.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="user_card">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">


                    <h3 id="form-title">Login</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form.as_p}}
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                                <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Login">
                            </div>
                    </form>

                </div>

</body>
```

**dashboard.html**

```
{%  extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<br>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <h5>Patients:</h5>
        <hr>
        <a class="btn btn-sm" href="">+ Create Patient</a>

        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Patient</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Can anybody see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you should change this line

```
    return redirect('index')
```

to

```
    return redirect('APPNAME:index')
```

refer to

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: I still got the same error. I think this is documentation for django3. I'm using 2.2

Comment: with Django2 i thought it was something like:  return reverse('appname:index')

Comment: Brilliant! It was return redirect('appname:index') Many thanks!!